# swift Using predicate

Tags: swift, predicate

```
request.predicate=NSPredicate( format:"lnameID= \(light.valueForKey("lnameID"))",nil);
```

When using the request.predicate in **Swift**,it goes wrong.

How to solve the problem in the format " xx "xx" xx" ?

Comment: as you could see in the documentation there is no _Swift_ implementation of the `+predicateWithFormat:` class method (it looks the various arguments' list is ObjC specific stuff): https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPredicate_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSPredicate/predicateWithFormat:, but there are `–init(predicateWithFormat:arguments:)` or `init(predicateWithFormat:argumentArray:)` which you can use as substitute method, if the block-based version is satisfying enough.

Comment: @holex: The docs seem not to be up-to-date. There is a `convenience init(format predicateFormat: String, _ args: CVarArgType...)` method, and that is called as `NSPredicate(format:"...", arg1, arg2, ...).

Comment: @MartinR, that would be the 3rd type of init methods, which can be useful instead. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not use string interpolation when building predicates. This will give wrong
results or crash at runtime as soon as there are any special characters (like
single or double quotes) in the values.

Better use the `%@` placeholder, for example:

```
let lnameID = light.valueForKey("lnameID") as String // assuming that it is a string
request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "lnameID = %@", lnameID)
```

Comment: I have tried this.It goes wrong.Swift has changed.No %@ any more.

Comment: @StoneTia: I am pretty sure that `%@` still works in predicates. But you may have to cast the value to the correct type first, see updated answer.

Comment: Yes,great.It's OK.Thanks.But how to write in the new way "  \(variable)". variable like  light.valueForKey("lnameID"). =-=

Comment: @StoneTia: Do you mean "new way" == "string interpolation", such as `"\(...)"` ? That does not work with function calls, and you should not use it for building predicates as explained above.

Answer (score 0):

You can put escaped quotes around and the escaped variable within the string like so:

```
request.predicate=NSPredicate( format:"lnameID= \"\(light.valueForKey("lnameID"))\"",nil)
```

Or you can use a placeholder, `%@`, where quotes are generated, as seen in Martin R's answer. Using escaped quotes is the more native way to do it in swift.